# Display all strings from array in datatable

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that I get a row value from and it is formatted as follows: `String databaseVal = "00010-12-D2324, K2343-13-D234234"`.

I am trying to manipulate the data and output each line separated by a comma to a `DataTable`. This is the code I have so far:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in finalResults.Rows)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string pin = this.rowValue("DB_Values", dr);
    string[] splitValue = pin.Split(',');

    List<string> list = splitValue.ToList();

    foreach (string item in list)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(item.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 3));
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        equip1 = row[0].ToString();
        equip2 = row[1].ToString();
        equip3 = row[2].ToString();
    }
}
```

So the desired result would be that the table would have 2 rows with the following:

> Row 1: equip1=00010, equip2=12, equip3=D2324
>
> Row 2: equip1=K2343, equip2=13, equip3=D234234

Right now I just get the first row and not the second. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you doing with the `equipX` variables?  The code seems to work fine for me, provided you are doing something with the values before rewriting them.

Comment: @awh12, I am displaying them in a report. And I changed the names for this example. But the problem is I get one record but it skips the second. and in some cases there are 3 or 4.

Comment: Gotcha.  I ran the code locally and it seems to work fine for me; the only thing I had to do was define the columns of `dt` which I assume you do elsewhere.  Other than that, my `dt.Rows` Count was 2 and the final `foreach` loop executed as expected.

Comment: @awh112 it is not a reserved keyword

Comment: The instruction "DataTable dt = new DataTable();" should precede the first loop and columns should be added to dt.